# Quality of work suffering due to workload

Tags: professionalism, work-experience, productivity

I am 25 and have currently around 2 years of work experience. Further, I have quite recently changed my job to another company in our group.

I asked in my first position for review talks about me and my work, and one thing came up:

- I always try to please everybody and I am too nice. Hence, I get in the position of getting too much work from others, which I can fulfil as I am often quite fast in execution, but NOT in the greatest quality.

After one week in my current job, I feel the same is happening again. F.ex.: I prepared a presentation, content-wise it was extremely great BUT it had grammatical and syntactical errors, which I basically overlooked, because the pile of work on my desk was extremely high, as our company is currently in some kind of "startup phase".(I do not see much work as an excuse for not delivering great quality.)

I think that my new boss is not yet finding it annoying that there were errors in my presentation, but I want to prevent from getting it to this point.

How would you approach this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How would you approach this situation?

In your review, your boss if giving you the clear hint...

**Slow down!**

Spend more time on ensuring quality, even if it means you cannot agree to do everything for everyone.

Fast is good. But correct is (almost always) more important.

A presentation containing grammatical and syntactical errors can not only be embarrassing to you, but could cost your company (if it is presented externally). That simply shouldn't be happening repeatedly no matter what your workload might be.

If you aren't capable of managing your own workload, you need to talk to your boss and together come up with a strategy to deal with it. That might mean a To Do List, where new requests are added to the bottom and you get to them in time. Or it might mean filtering requests through your boss. Or you might come up with a better solution.

Don't wait yet another two years to address this problem. Fix it now. Reap the rewards in your next review.

Answer (score 8):

1. Talk to your boss and agree on the priorities of the job
2. Talk to your boss and agree on how long those jobs you think will take
3. If those jobs are overrunning talk to your boss and tell him why. Perhaps ask for help
4. For colleagues can help you. Communicate with them. You are new to the job they may know of what to do or whom to ask.

Bottom line. Talk.

Answer (score 3):

Try to prioritise your work.  Decide what is important *and* urgent and do that first.  Everything else will have to wait until you're done with the more important stuff.  Don't rush things.

Agree with your boss what your work should be.  If anybody else tries to give you work, refer them to your boss.  That way he/she can decide what you should be doing and what's not your job to do.  If nothing else, your boss will have a better idea what your workload really is.

Answer (score 2):

Proof read, spelling and grammar errors in a presentation are unacceptable. There are a host of proof reading tools you can use to help you.

You need to look at your problem from the right perspective.

You ARE rushing things and putting out sub quality work, this is something you need to take care of, not blame any other factor for. So complete a job, then check it. Don't make excuses you were in a hurry, that's not professional. Make the time and double check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start planning your work. Make a list of what you need to do this week, plus an estimate of how much time each task will take. Now factor in overhead time such as meetings (say 1 hour a day, depending on your company). Based on this you can commit to deadlines. Now when someone comes to you with a request, see if you can fit the work in. This might mean not doing another task.

Make sure that you can make good on promises you make, and do not say yes to new work if you feel it means that other deadlines will suffer. This could mean you have to say no to someone.

To smooth this process, try and find someone to coach you.